# Python ftplib and downloading filemasks

Tags: python, ftplib

I've made a lot of progress on this, and can now download 3 of 4 files just fine, however, one, the Wisconsin file contains timestamps that I can't have removed, and vary day to day and I'm struggling to figure out how to get the wildcards to work on those values with regular expressions.  I've posted my revised code below:

Examples of the file names are:

- `BCW_Daily SDP Yield.rpt2020-02-17***-09-02-32***.csv`
- `hbc_platelet_daily_02102020.csv`
- `MBC_ROLLING_YIELD_02172020.CSV`
- `IBC_SDP_Rolling_7Days_021720.CSV`

Any help is appreciated.

```
import datetime
import ftplib
import os

ftpdir =('/home/hospserv/inbound/platelet/')
savedir = "C:/FTP/"
archivedir = "C:/ftparchive/"
os.chdir(savedir)
today = datetime.date.today()
iltoday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
widate = (f"{today:%Y-%m-%d}")
ildate = (f"{iltoday:%m%d%Y}")
midate = (f"{today:%m%d%Y}")
indate = (f"{today:%m%d%y}")
filenameIN = ('IBC_SDP_Rolling_7Days_'+indate+'.CSV')
filenameWI = ('BCW_SDP_Rolling_7Days.rpt'***+widate+'*'+***'.csv')
filenameIL = ('hbc_platelet_daily_'+ildate+'.csv')
filenameMI = ('MBC_ROLLING_YIELD_'+midate+'.CSV')
dlfiles = [filenameMI,filenameIN,filenameWI,filenameIL]

connection = ftplib.FTP(host='xxx',user='xxx',passwd='xxx')
welcome = ftplib.FTP.getwelcome(connection)
print(welcome)
connection.cwd(ftpdir)

ftp_list = connection.nlst()

print(ftp_list)

for x in dlfiles:
    if x in ftp_list:
        connection.retrbinary("RETR "+x, open(os.path.join(savedir, x), 'wb').write)
    else:
        print(x+' fail')


connection.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
# import modules
import fnmatch
import datetime
import ftplib
import os

#define variables
ftpdir =('/home/hospserv/inbound/platelet/')
savedir = "C:/FTP/"
archivedir = "C:/ftparchive/"
filedir = "C:/DailyData/SDPS/"
os.chdir(savedir)
today = datetime.date.today()
iltoday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
widate = (f"{today:%Y-%m-%d}")
ildate = (f"{iltoday:%m%d%Y}")
midate = (f"{today:%m%d%Y}")
indate = (f"{today:%m%d%y}")
filenameIN = ('IBC_SDP_Rolling_7Days_'+indate+'.CSV')
pattern = ('BCW_SDP_Rolling_7Days.rpt'+widate+'*'+'.csv')
filenameIL = ('hbc_platelet_daily_'+ildate+'.csv')
filenameMI = ('MBC_ROLLING_YIELD_'+midate+'.CSV')

#create FTP connection
connection = ftplib.FTP(xxxxxxx)
connection.cwd(ftpdir)

#generate file list on FTP
ftp_list = connection.nlst()

#create wildcard string for WI file
wistring = fnmatch.filter(ftp_list,pattern)
filenameWI = str(wistring[0])

dlfiles = [filenameMI,filenameIN,filenameIL,filenameWI]

#download files from FTP to local
for x in dlfiles:
    if x in ftp_list:
        connection.retrbinary("RETR "+x, open(os.path.join(savedir, x), 'wb').write)

connection.quit()
```